# highlight calender holiday with background color

Tags: calendar

In `org-mode`, when I press `C-c C-d` to add agenda, I got below screen:
[image]

It's perfect to see current day has been marked with red background, how can I mark the holidays (say 12/25) with some background color also?

Comment: M-x calendar-mark-holidays will mark holiday with color, maybe add it to a hook will automatically mark after calendar loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of the customization option `calendar-mark-holidays-flag` says:

> Non-nil means mark dates of holidays in the calendar window.
>   The marking symbol is specified by the variable `calendar-holiday-marker'.

I suggest to enable this option. I've tested it with `emacs -Q` and it works in emacs 25.3.1.

The screenshot after additionally adding `calendar-mark-today` to `calendar-visible-today-hook` and adapting `calendar-today` face to your configuration:

[image: Image of calendar]